# MongoDB fails to update nested array in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a following JSON object in database,

```
{
    "_id": "FlightLegPaxRecord::UA::141::2019-09-07::ORD::DEN",
    "activeInd": "0",
    "additionalProperties": {},
    "arrivalAirport": "DEN",
    "carrierCode": "UA",
    "departureAirport": "ORD",
    "departureDate": "2019-09-07",
    "docType": "FlightLegPaxRecord",
    "flightNumber": "141",
    "fltLclOrigDt": "2019-09-07",

    "travelerCounts": [{
        "additionalProperties": {},
        "counts": [{
            "additionalProperties": {},
            "key": "J",
            "value": "7"
        }, {
            "additionalProperties": {},
            "key": "Y",
            "value": "0"
        }],
        "travelCountType": "ActionStatus"
    }, {
        "additionalProperties": {},
        "counts": [{
            "additionalProperties": {},
            "key": "J",
            "value": "44"
        }, {
            "additionalProperties": {},
            "key": "Y",
            "value": "274"
        }],
        "travelCountType": "ActualCapacity"
    }]
}
```

Following is my java code to update the **value** field of the **count** array which matches a **travelCountType**.

Following is my java code:

```
Map<String, String> queryMap = new HashMap<>();
queryMap.put("_id", "FlightLegPaxRecord::UA::141::2019-09-07::ORD::DEN");
queryMap.put("travelerCounts.travelCountType", "ActionStatus");
queryMap.put("travelerCounts.counts.key", "J");

Map<String, String> updQuery = new HashMap<>();
updQuery.put("travelerCounts.counts.$.value", "99");

Document query = constructDocument(queryMap);
Document setData = constructDocument(updQuery);
Document update = new Document();
update.append("$set", setData);
MongoCollection collection = database.getCollection(colName);
UpdateResult result = collection.updateOne(query, update);

private Document constructDocument(Map<String, String> searchQuery) {
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> searchIterator = searchQuery.entrySet().iterator();
Document query = new Document();

while (searchIterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = searchIterator.next();
    query.append(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}

return query;
}
```

After executing the code, i am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Cannot create field 'counts' in element {travelerCounts: [ { additionalProperties: {}, counts: [ { additionalProperties: {}, key: "J", value: "7" }, { additionalProperties: {}, key: "Y", value: "0" } ], travelCountType: "ActionStatus" }, { additionalProperties: {}, counts: [ { additionalProperties: {}, key: "J", value: "44" }, { additionalProperties: {}, key: "Y", value: "274" } ], travelCountType: "ActualCapacity" } ]}
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:967)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeUpdate(MongoCollectionImpl.java:951)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:613)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:608)
    at com.ual.noc.connector.service.MongoCrudServiceImpl.updateSingleDocument(MongoCrudServiceImpl.java:90)
    at com.ual.noc.connector.TestMongo.testUpdate(TestMongo.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    ... 17 more
```

I am not able to understand where i am going wrong. Please help me in resolving the issue. Thanks in advance. 
Please let me know if i need to elaborate the issue in more detail.

Comment: It's because you're updating a value inside an array, This document has complex structure since it has to filter on array inside an array maybe it would not be normal update using positional operators, What is your mongoDB version ?

Comment: mongoDB Version: 4.2.1. I was following [this](https://www.nodechef.com/docs/cloud-search/updates-documents-nested-in-arrays) concept for the update.

Comment: @palab : not sure how it's working in that link, but in general that error is right as you're trying to update one object in `travelerCounts` array without any positional operator

Comment: Can you tell what is the Java driver you are using? Also, did you try the update code in the _mongo shell_ before converting it to Java?

Comment: What would the output (or result) document look like _after the update_?

Comment: @Pallab I had updated the answer with some notes about the _error_. Let me know if the info is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the [update filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/).

The Java Code:

```
Bson queryFilter = eq( "_id", "FlightLegPaxRecord::UA::141::2019-09-07::ORD::DEN" );

List<Bson> arrayFilters = new ArrayList<>();
arrayFilters.add(new Document( "tc.travelCountType", "ActionStatus" )); // "tc" for "travelerCounts"
arrayFilters.add(new Document( "ct.key", "J" )); // "ct" for "travelerCounts.counts"
UpdateOptions​ updateOptions = new UpdateOptions​().arrayFilters(arrayFilters);

Bson update = set( "travelerCounts.$[tc].counts.$[ct].value", "99" );

UpdateResult result = collection.updateOne(queryFilter, update, updateOptions);
```

---

[**Edit ADD**]

The code `updQuery.put("travelerCounts.counts.$.value", "99")` will produce errors *or* an incorrect result. According to MongoDB documentation on [$ and Nested Arrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html#nested-arrays)

> The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse
>   more than one array....

The update in the query is a nested array with two levels. So, the solutions can be one of these:

1. The one I have already provided (above).
2. You can also use aggregation with the
   [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)
   method. The MongoDB version 4.2 has feature that allows using
   Aggregation pipeline instead of an *update*.
3. If you are using MongoDB versions 4.0 or earlier, you can use an
   aggregation and then an update on the aggregation result.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The code you provided works just fine!